# How do you get the File:// protocol to work in IE8?

Tags: internet-explorer-8, browser, file-uri

I am running a website on my local machine ("http://localhost/asdf") and trying to get some file:// protocol links to work.  In reality I'm trying to open a folder, not a specific file, but I can't get either to work.

I've put localhost in my "trusted zone", I've tried every combo of "file" ,":", some number of "/" and then a whole bunch of different paths, but encoded and not encoded.

Nothing I do causes anything to open when I click on the link.  If I copy the link destination, and paste that in the browser address window, then it works as expected.

Anyone know the secret?

Comment: It just doesn't open anything, nothing happens.  It works for my client just fine, which I guess is what counts, but not for me in my dev environment.  I have no idea why, I've checked every IE setting I can think of.

Comment: See http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ieinternals/archive/2011/08/12/internet-explorer-9.0.2-update-changes-file-protocol-and-cookie-naming.aspx for the explanation of why this has failed since August 2011. Prior to that, it should have worked in general.

Answer (score 2):

Add your intranet site in the Intranet Zone in Security Tab.

Answer (score 1):

Generally `file:///` URLs shouldn't work on [pages downloaded via HTTP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_URI_scheme#Mozilla), that they sometimes work in IE7 and earlier is a security issue.

Comment: It's more complicated than that. See http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ieinternals/archive/2011/08/12/internet-explorer-9.0.2-update-changes-file-protocol-and-cookie-naming.aspx

Answer (score 1):

We found that `window.open` method using the file protocol in the URL causes the method to fail. Under I.E. the behavior is erratic. In some instances, the object mentioned in the URL is opened but the window object instance is not created. In others, the URL failes to open. In some instances we noted that under Windows 7, the URL opens, under XP it does not. Under Safari,Chrome and Firefox, the URL never opened.

Answer (score -1):

Local server is something different than just file://, that should work in IE as it is. However, if you probably want to check out [apache alias](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/1.3/mod/mod_alias.html) and link that folder to your server. Btw, you should not use file protocol anyway, it will not work on production.

Comment: The web app is running in a intranet environment, with the file:// pointing to locations on various file servers that are on the same network as the current user.  The purpose of the link is to open the a folder for the user to manipulate: move files around, drag new files into folders, rename files/folder etc.  It would be really overkill to try to build all that functionality into a browser app.

Comment: It's your call, yet I suggest using absolute paths on the server. File stream is definitely not as much reliable.

Comment: This has nothing to do with file streams or absolute paths on the server.  Thanks for trying to help but you don't understand the situation.

Comment: His point, even if not well made, is that `http://intranet/` is very different than `file://intranet/`.