# Image path to store in database

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, image

I am trying to retreive an image from the path stored in sql database. When I try to load the http request, I get the image, but when I try to save it on a network path and retrieve that, i do not get an image

When, i write my image shared location to the browser, it works.

```
file://networkshared1/Try/Image1.jpg
```

When, I save this url to the database and retrieve it, I do not get anything.

C# code:

```
Image1.ImageUrl = "file://networkshared1/Try/Image1.jpg"; //DOES NOT WORK
Image1.ImageUrl ="http://something;" //IT WORKS
```

Comment: The `file:` protocol is different from the `http` protocol. The `file` protocol is for images on your local system, not something you'd get over the internet. You should use the `http` protocol.

Comment: include the network folder as an virtual directory in IIS:
You can then access it like this:
http://something/virtualDir/imageXyz.jpg

Comment: But I have it stored on my network drive. And i want to access the image from there.

Comment: @hellotemp9 Then that network drive needs to be mapped to an IIS virtual directory and then you can serve it from whatever URL you provide to that virtual directory.

Comment: @BrianRudolph No , it doesnt work

Comment: look at the answer of @GeorgeStocker and me, thats the solution.
If you create a virtual directory your app pool user must have access rights for the folder!

Comment: I can access files to the network folder so cant i access image from network folder ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2762819/how-do-you-get-the-file-protocol-to-work-in-ie8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the following steps:

Add Virtual Directory to your application in IIS
[image: Add Virtual Directory to your application in IIS]

Give it an alias.In your case this would be your network folder here.

[image]

you can see the virtual directory now.

[image]

check under which app pool the app is running

[image]
Go the respective app pool. In my case it is running under the admin account (not good! but I have all access rights :-))

[image]

Add the app pool account to the ACL list of the network folder and give it the respective rights.

[image]

Now you can access the file in your application via http as you can see in the url:

[image]